# Multiple Tabs of Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been building an android app in eclipse, it has swipe gestures, my problem is that all the pages are for some reason duplicate, meaning they show the exact same content as the first tab.

How do I work on each page individually? and how do I get it not to duplicate?

Here is the code:

'

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/Hey" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/Cont." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="@string/con" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:text="@string/believe" />



    <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/section_label2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content
       />
```

'

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some of your code, so we can help you out?

Comment: Please Edit your question and post the java code too there and see the proper format of posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

You might look for this: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Please look at the android developer pages first and foremost, they have such a good documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: That sounded a little rude, sorry. Where do you think I should look in the article?

Comment: Sorry if you think that I'm rude, but you are asking about how to make them not duplicate, and I thought that you haven't read the documentation yet, and you are trying to make it your own way. The whole article is about swipe views created using the ViewPager widget. The ViewPager is a layout widget in which each child view is a separate page (a separate tab) in the layout. Hope this one helps now.

Comment: I didnt say You were rude, I was saying what I Had previously said was rude.

Comment: I think my problem is I dont really know any java. and I think thats why I am having a really hard time. :/  Do you know of a site, thats really easy to learn from? Thanks

Comment: On youtube there is a channel "thenewboston" you can watch the beginner lessons, and also I think that he has advanced lessons after you finish the beginner once. Another option but paid, is Lynda.com.